# ProcessPoolExecutor read-only variable speed discrepancy

Tags: python, python-3.x, concurrency, multiprocessing, python-internals

I have two versions of a multiprocessing program using `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` (Python 3.6, Linux) with surprising speed discrepancies despite seemingly minor changes (one is ~3x slower than the other).

Each child process executes a simple function that reads from a large dict (it does not alter it) and returns a result.

1. The first version of the function passes the dict into `executor.submit()` as an argument.
2. The second version of the function reads from the global dict directly.

### Code samples

**Variable passed in**:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import concurrent.futures, pstats, sys, cProfile

BIG_DICT = {i: 2*i for i in range(10000)}
def foo(d):
    return d[0]

with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
    tasks = [executor.submit(foo, BIG_DICT) for _ in range(100000)]

    for task in concurrent.futures.as_completed(tasks):
        task.result()
```

**Global variable read from**:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import concurrent.futures, pstats, sys, cProfile

BIG_DICT = {i: 2*i for i in range(10000)}
def foo():
    return BIG_DICT[0]

with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
    tasks = [executor.submit(foo) for _ in range(100000)]

    for task in concurrent.futures.as_completed(tasks):
        task.result()
```

### Ideas

I've profiled both versions of the program using cProfile and the majority of execution time seems to be spent waiting for locks. The global version only waits for about 10 seconds, while the pass-in version waits for almost 80 seconds!

From what I understand, when a process is forked it should make a copy of its parent's memory. As the program is multiprocessed and `BIG_DICT` is never actually modified after creation, there shouldn't be any need for locking to maintain state consistency between submitting each process.

Since `BIG_DICT` needs to be copied into the memory space of each child process in both versions, why is there so much discrepancy in execution time?

A couple of ideas I have floating around:

- Implementation detail of `ProcessPoolExecutor`
- GIL quirk
- Some sort of Python runtime/OS optimisation

### Profiling results

**Variable passed in**:

```
         7672287 function calls in 92.434 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time, cumulative time
   List reduced from 247 to 12 due to restriction <0.05>

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
   460133   75.428    0.000   75.428    0.000 {method 'acquire' of '_thread.lock' objects}
   100001    7.034    0.000    7.034    0.000 {built-in method posix.write}
   100001    2.490    0.000    2.490    0.000 {method '__enter__' of '_multiprocessing.SemLock' objects}
   100001    0.686    0.000   78.344    0.001 _base.py:196(as_completed)
    90033    0.553    0.000   75.879    0.001 threading.py:263(wait)
   100000    0.548    0.000   13.639    0.000 process.py:449(submit)
   190033    0.366    0.000    0.713    0.000 _base.py:174(_yield_finished_futures)
   100000    0.351    0.000    0.598    0.000 _base.py:312(__init__)
    90033    0.327    0.000   76.335    0.001 threading.py:533(wait)
   100001    0.261    0.000    7.617    0.000 connection.py:181(send_bytes)
   480065    0.260    0.000    0.382    0.000 threading.py:239(__enter__)
   100001    0.258    0.000   11.329    0.000 queues.py:339(put)


   Ordered by: internal time, cumulative time
   List reduced from 247 to 12 due to restriction <0.05>

Function                                                    was called by...
                                                                ncalls  tottime  cumtime
{method 'acquire' of '_thread.lock' objects}                <-   90033    0.078    0.078  threading.py:251(_acquire_restore)
                                                                190033    0.391    0.391  threading.py:254(_is_owned)
                                                                180066   74.956   74.956  threading.py:263(wait)
                                                                     1    0.003    0.003  threading.py:1062(_wait_for_tstate_lock)
{built-in method posix.write}                               <-  100001    7.034    7.034  connection.py:365(_send)
{method '__enter__' of '_multiprocessing.SemLock' objects}  <-  100001    2.490    2.490  synchronize.py:95(__enter__)
_base.py:196(as_completed)                                  <-
threading.py:263(wait)                                      <-   90033    0.553   75.879  threading.py:533(wait)
process.py:449(submit)                                      <-  100000    0.548   13.639  local.py:13(<listcomp>)
_base.py:174(_yield_finished_futures)                       <-  190033    0.366    0.713  _base.py:196(as_completed)
_base.py:312(__init__)                                      <-  100000    0.351    0.598  process.py:449(submit)
threading.py:533(wait)                                      <-   90032    0.327   76.334  _base.py:196(as_completed)
                                                                     1    0.000    0.001  threading.py:828(start)
connection.py:181(send_bytes)                               <-  100001    0.261    7.617  queues.py:339(put)
threading.py:239(__enter__)                                 <-  100000    0.070    0.116  _base.py:174(_yield_finished_futures)
                                                                100000    0.033    0.051  _base.py:405(result)
                                                                100000    0.083    0.108  queue.py:115(put)
                                                                 90032    0.040    0.058  threading.py:523(clear)
                                                                 90033    0.034    0.050  threading.py:533(wait)
queues.py:339(put)                                          <-  100000    0.258   11.329  process.py:449(submit)
                                                                     1    0.000    0.000  process.py:499(shutdown)
```

**Global variable read from**:

```
         5949819 function calls in 27.158 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time, cumulative time
   List reduced from 247 to 12 due to restriction <0.05>

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
   160569   10.072    0.000   10.072    0.000 {method 'acquire' of '_thread.lock' objects}
   100001    5.453    0.000    5.453    0.000 {method '__enter__' of '_multiprocessing.SemLock' objects}
   100001    5.338    0.000    5.338    0.000 {built-in method posix.write}
   100000    0.883    0.000    1.163    0.000 _base.py:312(__init__)
   100000    0.477    0.000   15.671    0.000 process.py:449(submit)
   100001    0.438    0.000    6.133    0.000 connection.py:181(send_bytes)
   100001    0.304    0.000   12.921    0.000 queues.py:339(put)
   100000    0.304    0.000    0.304    0.000 process.py:116(__init__)
   100001    0.277    0.000    0.432    0.000 reduction.py:38(__init__)
   100000    0.267    0.000    0.333    0.000 threading.py:334(notify)
   100000    0.240    0.000    0.747    0.000 queue.py:115(put)
   100006    0.238    0.000    0.280    0.000 threading.py:215(__init__)


   Ordered by: internal time, cumulative time
   List reduced from 247 to 12 due to restriction <0.05>

Function                                                    was called by...
                                                                ncalls  tottime  cumtime
{method 'acquire' of '_thread.lock' objects}                <-   15142    0.007    0.007  threading.py:251(_acquire_restore)
                                                                115142    0.038    0.038  threading.py:254(_is_owned)
                                                                 30284   10.022   10.022  threading.py:263(wait)
                                                                     1    0.004    0.004  threading.py:1062(_wait_for_tstate_lock)
{method '__enter__' of '_multiprocessing.SemLock' objects}  <-  100001    5.453    5.453  synchronize.py:95(__enter__)
{built-in method posix.write}                               <-  100001    5.338    5.338  connection.py:365(_send)
_base.py:312(__init__)                                      <-  100000    0.883    1.163  process.py:449(submit)
process.py:449(submit)                                      <-  100000    0.477   15.671  global.py:13(<listcomp>)
connection.py:181(send_bytes)                               <-  100001    0.438    6.133  queues.py:339(put)
queues.py:339(put)                                          <-  100000    0.304   12.921  process.py:449(submit)
                                                                     1    0.000    0.000  process.py:499(shutdown)
process.py:116(__init__)                                    <-  100000    0.304    0.304  process.py:449(submit)
reduction.py:38(__init__)                                   <-  100001    0.277    0.432  reduction.py:48(dumps)
threading.py:334(notify)                                    <-  100000    0.267    0.333  queue.py:115(put)
queue.py:115(put)                                           <-  100000    0.240    0.747  process.py:449(submit)
threading.py:215(__init__)                                  <-  100000    0.238    0.280  _base.py:312(__init__)
                                                                     3    0.000    0.000  queue.py:27(__init__)
                                                                     1    0.000    0.000  queues.py:67(_after_fork)
                                                                     2    0.000    0.000  threading.py:498(__init__)
```

Comment: serialization of BIG_DICT?